# django urls.py changes not reflecting

Tags: python, django

I have an API running at the endpoint: **sitename.net/sitename-api/myapi**. 
It was working perfectly fine until I decided to change the url to **sitename.net/sitename-api/myapi1**. Just added **1**.

This is what my `myapi/urls.py` file looks like:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import myapi_view

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^myapi1$', myapi_view.as_view())
]
```

But I still get **404** when I try to reach myapi1. I tried deleting `pycache` and restarting the development server but it did not help. Can anyone here suggest a possible solution?

INFO:
This is what my `sitename-api/urls.py` file looks like :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls import include

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^sitename-api/', include('myapi.urls')),
    url(r'^sitename-api/', include('anotherapi.urls'))
]
```

Comment: If you run debug mode I believe you get a list of all urls django recognizes? Perhaps that will give you more insight.

Comment: I ran that. I see "../myapi" there instead of "../myapi1". Which leads me to believe the changes are not being reflected but I dont understand why.

Comment: apologies if this sounds patronising (it probably does, but I feel I have to ask) - but are you sure you saved the changes?

Comment: Try adding a print() statement to your myapi/urls.py, see if it hits that. Otherwise I'd have no idea.

Comment: @ThePjot The print statement is running so yeah the urls.py file is being compiled. But I dont know why the url change is not being reflected. I tried switching browsers and clearing browser cache.

Comment: Could you share `anotherapi.urls` file ?

Answer (score 0):

Normally Django enforces a trailing slash at the end:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import myapi_view

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^myapi1/$', myapi_view.as_view())
]
```

Comment: But r'^myapi$' has been working fine for the past 6 months. The problem is that even after changing myapi to myapi1, I can still get to myapi page and myapi1 throws 404

Comment: Is it possible that `/myapi` is still defined in some other file?